# MySQL and C# - Unknow column 'email' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql

I've edited my code and for some reason I get this error. It was working fine before. Anyway, here's my login code for my form:

```
string command = "SELECT email, password FROM uc_users WHERE email = @email";
        try
        {
            // COMMAND DETAILS
            MySqlCommand email = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);

            // PARAMETERS
            email.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);

            // READER DETAILS
            MySqlDataReader dr;

            // CHECK DETAILS               
            dr = email.ExecuteReader();
            if (!dr.Read()) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid login details.");
            }

            string passwordC = dr.GetString(1);
            string saltedPass = Security.HashSalt.SaltedHash(txtPassword.Text);
            bool match = IsPasswordMatch(passwordC, saltedPass);

            if (match == true)
            {
                connection.Close();
                string email2 = txtEmail.Text;
                frmZilent frm = new frmZilent(email2);
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid login details.");
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MySQL Error - Code AHx004: " +ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

The connection is already open by the way. Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't using salts correctly; your data is not secure.

Comment: Are you sure your table has `email` column, maybe its not the code that has changed, but somebody changed the name of the column in table.

Comment: I have some salts in my code, just not here.

Comment: I'm sure yes. I haven't edited the table.

Comment: @PROZILENTEXX: Wrong.  The whole point of a salt is that it's unique to each user.

Comment: I fixed it. Found out that my code was pointing to the wrong table for some reason. Thanks for the suggestions guys :)

Comment: @SLaks How can I do that then?

Comment: @PROZILENTEXX: Use PBKDFv2, generate a secure random salt every time you create a password, and store it in the database.